# How Do I Create a User Role that Can Only CRUD a Single Content-type?

Tags: nodes, users

OK, so I know how to create roles and messed around with the People->Permissions->Roles screen.  My goal is to create a single user role that will have only one function -- to administer the calendar events for the client site.

The first thing I did was to create a view to act as the overview of the available content.  I added in the Login Destinations module and set it to send the user directly to the Events content overview view.

I checked the following role permissions at the Node level as:

- Access the content overview page
- View published content
- View own unpublished content
- View content revisions
- Revert content revisions
- Delete content revisions

And at the content-type node itself:

- Calendar Event: Create new content
- Calendar Event: Edit own content
- Calendar Event: Edit any content
- Calendar Event: Delete own content
- Calendar Event: Delete any content

So, when I log in as my event administrating user, I am redirected to the overview page, as expected.  But when I click on the link to the node, I get this:

"You are not authorized to access this page."

So, my question is two-fold.  1) Is there a better way (read: built-in) to implement the "overview" of the content that I'm not aware of? 2) Am I using the People->Permissions->Roles as designed?  If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Scott.

Answer (score 2):

The Permissions section is broken out across content types. You can create a new group, put that user into it, and give that group permission to CrUD one or more content types. Allow this user no other permission in any other content type (outside of calendar).

To overcome the 'overview' page problem, is **View published content** checked?

[image]

Comment: OK.  This is the permissions page, right?  (Mine looks a tad different but essentially the same.)  I want this user role (when you said Group, you meant Role, right?) to access the list of content and *only* the list of content.  Not the main site.  Just a list of content.  I have the stuff above checked as you indicated.  But it still doesn't work.  But I appreciate the speedy response!

Comment: Yes, Group==User Role. Could you post some screen shots of what you have? That might help a bit more.

Comment: I'd love to but I'm new to this stackexchange and can't post images until my rep is over 10...

Comment: OK.  So what I want here is for this user role to *only* see the overview of the specific content type.  Not the rest of the site at all.  Just a list he/she can CrUD as they see fit.  Once they log out, then can then navigate to the site normally.  And Yes -- I do have the View Published Content checked.  But I'm not sure that's what I want, ya know?